# How to retain drop down values when drop down data are populated from database?

Tags: drop-down-menu, selected, retain

I know this question might be irritating to repeat and repeat about retaining values in drop down after submit but i tried other solution suggested but most of them are not the same with mine...some says to indicate the selected value but i failed to implement it with mine...My situation is ..I have a drop down lists of Party list and is populated from my set of records in my DB...Here is my sample code:

```
        echo '<label>Party List:&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    echo '<select name="PartyList" id="PartyList" value="" class="smallInput" required>';
        echo '<option value="-1">ALL</option>';
        while($ROW = mysql_fetch_array($PartyListRow)){
            echo '<option value="' . $ROW['PLID'] . '">' . $ROW['PLName'] . '</option>';
        }
    echo '</select>';
```

.I hope someone can atleast give me a hint...please don't close this question...

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>Party List:</label>
<select name="PartyList" id="PartyList" class="smallInput" required>'
    <option value="-1">ALL</option>
    <? while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($PartyListRow)) { ?>
         <option value="<?= $row['PLID']?>"><?= $row['PLName']?></option>
    <? } ?>
</select>
```

Please use `mysqli` and post more details about what you are using (query php code etc)